# Regex checking runs infinite time

Tags: java, regex

I have written the below regex so that,this regex will not match with the input; It is working but the loop runs infinite time. How to resolve the issue

```
String originalRegex ="(?s)\\00|\\+ADw-|\\+AD4-|%[0-9a-f]{2}|System[.][a-z]|javascript\\s*:|>(?:\".*|^'.*|[^a-z]'.*|'[^a-z].*|')[-+\\*/%=&|^~\"']|\\?.*<:|\\(\\s*[a-z]{2,}\\.[a-z]{2,}.*\\)";
String xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><configuration xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/api/2.2\" timestamp=\"str111\" version=\"2.2\"><domain account=\"4af17966-c841-4b97-a94a-edd7a0769\" /></configuration>";
String freetext = ">(?:\".*|^'.*|[^a-z]'.*|'[^a-z].*|')[-+\\*/%=&|^~\"']|\\?.*<:";
final Pattern PATTERN_1 = Pattern.compile(freetext);
Matcher matcher = PATTERN_1.matcher(xmlData);

while (!matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Good Job");
}
```

Comment: Which language? The reason would probably be apparent if this was mentioned, as someone could look up the documentation for the `.find()` method.

Comment: You shouldn't be using regex to parse XML.

Comment: replace `while` by `if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's `.find()` method returns "*true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern*" - [see the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29). In your code, if no matches are found then:

```
while (!matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Good Job");
}
```

evaluates to:

```
while (!false) {
    System.out.println("Good Job");
}
```

or, even simpler:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Good Job");
}
```

Thus, your infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

From the javadocs of `Matcher.find()`

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.
>
> Returns: true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence
>   matches this matcher's pattern

you should Ideally use

```
while(matcher.find())
```

above will try to match input string continuously based on regex pattern.

your while loop will either goes into infinite loop if it is not able to find a pattern or if the match is found it will exit the loop, either way its of no use

```
while(!matcher.find())
```

However if you want to check if it doesn't match then you can use `if`

```
if(!matcher.find()){
   //No Matches
} else {
   //Atleast one Match
}
```

One more tip. If you are trying to parse XML, Regex might not be a right candidate. Try to use one of many XML parsers available.